# How to get last emitted value of on Observable in the subscription when next is called after the subscription?

Tags: angular, rxjs

How can I subscribe and log the last value when next is called after subscription ?

Here is the [working demo stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7fhsbv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts), how or is it possible to get value only the last value i.e.`123` that is emitted after the subscription inside the subscribe method or any other alternative ? I used `last()` but it doesn't logs any value at all. I want the subscription to run only once and use the last value

```
    import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { last } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name: string;
  subject = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subject.next(456);

    this.getData()
      // .pipe(last())
      .subscribe(console.log);

      // this next is being done in another component after subscription so putting it here to mimic the behavior
     this.subject.next(123);

  }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Comment: your example already logs `123`, it is not clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Sorry about that edit my question, I want to print only `123` subscribe to only last emitted value, thats why I am trying  to use `last()`

Comment: If I understand you properly, `take(1)` should do it

Comment: @MrkSef no `take(1)` logs only the initial value https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n25kys?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `last()` as the subject does not currently complete. You need to call `complete()` on the subject to be able to use it:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.subject.next(456);

  this.getData()
    .pipe(last())
    .subscribe(console.log);

  this.subject.next(123);
  this.subject.complete();
}
```

Your **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ewjga5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)**