# RxJS takeLast function Stops Everything

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

When I use `pipe` and `takeLast`, then the whole process stops.

Here is my original code:

```
this.request$.subscribe(req => {
  this._service.run(req!).subscribe(res => {
    this._service.fetch().subscribe(resources => {
      console.log('hi'); // This 'hi' logs two times, but I want to get only the last 'hi'.
    });
  });
});
```

Here is my try:

```
this.request$.subscribe(req => {
  this._service.run(req!).subscribe(res => {
    this._service
      .fetch()
      .pipe(takeLast(1))
      .subscribe({
        next: x => console.log('got value ' + x),
        error: err => console.error('something wrong occurred: ' + err),
        complete: () => console.log('hi')
      });
  });
});
```

However, nothing happends in my try and nothing is logged anymore.

**Updated my question**

I have updated my second example as below, but not working yet:

```
this.request$.pipe(
  mergeMap((req) => this._service.run(req!)),
  mergeMap((res) => this._service.fetch().pipe(takeLast(1)))
).subscribe((resources) => {
  console.log('hi'); // This line is not executed, but I expect to be executed one time.
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't subscribe inside another subscribe

Comment: Beyond that we'll need much more info than "stops working"

Comment: by `stops working`, I mean `hi` is not logged in the console anymore when I use my second example. And I also didn't understand your first comment. What should I do then?

Comment: Yes I appreciate that, what is your input stream and what do you expect? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: If you don't understand my first comment then I'd suggest you may need to read more on [RXJS](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) and functional programming in general

Comment: [Or this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52317734/542251)

Comment: Okay, I will read them to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get last emitted value of on Observable in the subscription when next is called after the subscription?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67445003/how-to-get-last-emitted-value-of-on-observable-in-the-subscription-when-next-is)

Comment: @dota2pro, let me check and tell you then.

Comment: I updated my question, but not solved yet.

Comment: Like I said, *what is your input stream and what do you expect?* You still haven't given us a [mcve] to work with. There isn't enough information in this question to answer

Comment: this._service.fetch() returns an `Observable<ResourceInterface[]`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the post I commented you need to `complete()` observable so that Rxjs knows which is the last one, See [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wbrfgb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { from, Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { last, takeLast, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name: string;
  request$ = new Observable<any>();
  end$ = new Subject();
  ngOnInit() {
    this.request$ = from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); // create Observable
    this.request$
      .pipe(
        // mergeMap((req) => this._service.runRequest(req!)),
        // mergeMap((res) => this._service.fetchResources().pipe
        takeLast(1),
        takeUntil(this.end$)
      )
      .subscribe(resources => {
        console.log('hi'); // This line is not executed, but I expect to be executed one time.
      });

    this.end$.complete(); // Finish Subject to end subscription
  }
}
```

Comment: my `this.request$` is of type `Observable<MyInterface | undefined>;`. Does this make the problem for me?

Comment: should not, I just created a random observable

Comment: Your code works, but in my code, when I uncomment `mergeMap((req) => this._service.run(req!))` then the console.log stops working.

Comment: `this._service.run(req!))` returns `Observable<any>`.

Comment: Create a stackblitz and post it, probably this pipe inside, put it outside   `mergeMap((res) => this._service.fetch().pipe(takeLast(1)))` //Remove this pipe